# Messed up my app and now it crashes on load. Don't understand error from catlog

Tags: java, android

I had an app that was working as expected.  I didn't like the UI due to unknown behaviors of android so I decided to redesign the XML file.  I created a new_layout.xml file, designed it as I wanted and then refactored > renamed the activity_main.xml file to activity_main_old.xml and refactored > renamed new_layout.xml to activity_main.xml.

The app crashed saying something about not being able to cast a Button to ImageButton, but the weird thing is that I only copy/pasted the elements from the one XML file to the other, so there should have been no issues since the names were the same.

As a result, I thought that maybe the names of each of the element were conflicting with the original layout (now activity_main_old.xml) and so I deleted this file out of the project.  Then I refactored > renamed the activity_main.xml to something more meaningful (scoreboard.xml).  I changed the setContentView() method to the next scoreboard layout id.

I don't understand the error messages that I'm getting and would appreciate any help I can get please:

```
12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ultimatescoreclock/com.example.ultimatescoreclock.ScoreboardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at com.example.ultimatescoreclock.ScoreboardActivity.onCreate(ScoreboardActivity.java:207)
12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
12-27 15:31:24.744: E/AndroidRuntime(4800):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
E/AndroidRuntime(4800): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(4800): at com.example.ultimatescoreclock.ScoreboardActivity.onCreate(ScoreboardActivity.java:207)
```

`NullPointerException` at line 207 in `ScoreboardActivity.java` class.

There is no code in your question, so it is hard to tell what is going on but, the reason could be you are trying to do some call on `null` reference.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Now that you extract the info it seems so easy to read.  I forgot to transfer one of the elements over.  I commented out the findViewById line but the onClickListener was still present in my code.  I just re-created that element and it worked perfectly!

Comment: @JimThornton: You are welcome. Glad it helped. I would suggest spend sometime on how to read stack trace. That really saves lot of time.